# Сохранить файл без "окна диалога" используя TChromium in Delphi

Tags: jquery, delphi, google-chrome

Есть код который подгружает на сайт необходимые скрипты(html2canvas.js, FileSaver.js, canvastoBlob.js), создает canvas и соответственно его сохраняет, но выдает стандартный диалог сохранения файлов.

Имя файла всегда одинаковое, то бишь нужно файл еще перезаписывать.

```
procedure TMainForm.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
//подключаем 3 скрипта для сохранения картинки.
loadHtml2Canvas;
//выполняем скрипт
 crm.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript(
 'setTimeout(function(){'+
 'var body = jQuery("iframe").contents().find("body");'+
 //создаем канву
 ' html2canvas(body, {'+
 '   onrendered: function(canvas) {'+
 '    canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {'+
       //Cохраняем
 '     saveAs(blob, "file.jpeg");'+
 '    }, "image/jpeg");'+
 '   }'+ //end onrendered
 '});'+//end html2canvas
 '}, 900);',//end setTimeout
 crm.Browser.MainFrame.Url,
0);
end;
```

Как можно отловить|обойти окно сохранения файлов вызванное TChromium сохранив файл просто в корень с программой? Возможно есть событие в самом TChromium перед сохранением файлов либо путь попроще?

**Решение (after 20 minutes):**
в TChromium есть событие **OnBeforeDownload** в нем вызовем функцию Cont куда передадим путь и второй параметр наше окно диалога = False, окна не будет = файл сохранен.

```
procedure TMainForm.crmBeforeDownload(Sender: TObject;
  const browser: ICefBrowser; const downloadItem: ICefDownloadItem;
  const suggestedName: ustring; const callback: ICefBeforeDownloadCallback);
begin
  callback.Cont(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + suggestedName, False);
end;
```

Comment: Запостите решение ответом и отметьте его, как правильное, галкой

Comment: Ок, пишет что могу принять решение только через два дня :)

Answer (score 1):

в TChromium есть событие OnBeforeDownload в нем вызовем функцию Cont куда передадим путь и второй параметр наше окно диалога = False, окна не будет = файл сохранен.

```
procedure TMainForm.crmBeforeDownload(Sender: TObject;
  const browser: ICefBrowser; const downloadItem: ICefDownloadItem;
  const suggestedName: ustring; const callback: ICefBeforeDownloadCallback);
begin
  callback.Cont(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + suggestedName, False);
end;
```